# Bootstrap Navbar Automatic Toggling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am attempting to use Bootstrap to build a navbar for my website. I am have tried to use the toggling feature that allows the menu to be more accessible on mobile devices. When I zoom in to 200% on my browser, it toggles fine and works great. When I connect to my site on my phone however, it fails to automatically toggle.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-server"></i> Server List</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php#server">Servers</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Purchase<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Highlighted Spot</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">My Servers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Favorites</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
              <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I've tried everything I've found online to no avail, so I greatly thank anyone who helps me out with this!

Comment: Do you have the following in the `head` of your HTML file:  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` ?

Comment: @Angelique that worked! Thank you so much, I feel like a complete idiot now.